# Is there a way to calculate the whole time which Typed.js takes?

Tags: javascript, howler.js, typed.js

I will calculate the whole time which [Typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) takes to type custom sentences. I will start a soundtrack with some negative delay (depends on that soundtrack) at the end of typing finish time.

[image: combination of sentence and soundtracs]

All sentence typing takes `n` milliseconds; I want to start the soundtrack (n - delay) milliseconds from the beginning of the typing process.

This `n` can be calculated from `fadeOutDelay`, `startDelay`, `typeSpeed`, but the diffing which Typed.js uses not to remove the previous sentence. Involvement of diffing algorithm in `n` calculation looks a bad practice for me, and I want to keep that diffing algorithm  .

Here is **packages** I use:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "howler": "2.2.1",
    "typed.js": "2.0.11"
  },
```

All other solutions are welcomed.

### **edited**

I added [a simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/KKTCondition/za5gnqe6/) with hard-coded timing for some sound.

1. sound will no be played in this demo :)
2. All of the stuff and timing must be dynamically calculated.

Comment: Why don't you start by making a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks for mentioning that link